# What is the longest distance a 13th-level monk can jump while attacking on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, monk, attack

### Context

During last session in a game that I GM, the party got ambushed by NPC monks leaping from the trees. They were hiding high up in very big [Sawtooth Oak Trees](https://images.app.goo.gl/x42Kn2hJ64ZQSYyU9), then jumped in a horizontal direction towards a flying PC warlock to attack him with their darts. The size of the trees – average height of 40-50 foot in this scenario – allowed the monks to run on some of the branches and/or tree trunk before jumping.

In the heat of the moment, the warlock player convinced me that jumping distance is only 10 feet when doubled, so they wouldn't be able to reach him with their attacks.  It didn't make any sense to me in the moment, to have 50 feet of movement as a monk but not be able to jump further than 10 feet.  But the party was already having a rough time, and I didn't want to slow down combat by looking it up, so I ruled in favour of the party.

Now, post-session, I'm looking into the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Movement):

> **Long Jump.**  When you make a long jump, ***you cover a number of feet up to your Strength score*** if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump.  When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.
>
> This rule assumes that the height of your jump doesn't matter, such as a jump across a stream or chasm. At your DM's option, you must succeed on a DC 10 Strength (Athletics) check to clear a low obstacle (no taller than a quarter of the jump's distance), such as a hedge or low wall. Otherwise, you hit it.
>
> When you land in difficult terrain, you must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity (Acrobatics) check to land on your feet.  Otherwise, you land prone.

### Question

Please take the following details into consideration when answering this question.

The monk:

- has 50 feet of movement (base)
- has a Strength score of 16
- is able to run the required 10 feet
- takes Step of the Wind as bonus action
- saves the Action for attacking

> **Step of the Wind.** You can spend 1 ki point to take the Disengage or Dash action as a bonus action on your turn, and your ***jump distance is doubled*** for the turn.

**What is the longest distance the monk can jump within this framework?**

Comment: I might be wrong as English is not my mother tongue but "They were hiding high up in the trees for an ambush, then jumped in a horizontal direction towards a flying PC warlock to attack him" how could they run the 10 feets required to take the leap? Are the tree branches 10 feet long and could the tip of the branch hold the monk weight?

Comment: @Squirrel See Q. Short reply to your questions: yes, the trees were big enough to allow such movement, and they didn't jump from the tip of the branches ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### The Monk can make a *long* jump up to 32 feet.

As you quoted,

> **Long Jump.** When you make a long jump, ***you cover a number of feet up to your Strength score*** if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump.

If the monk's Strength score is 16, they would normally be able to make a long jump of 16 feet with a 10 foot running start.  Thanks to Step of the Wind, that distance is doubled to 32 feet.

Alternatively,

### The Monk can make a *high* jump of up to 12 feet.

The rules for high jumping state:

> **High Jump**. When you make a high jump, you leap into the air ***a number of feet equal to 3 + your Strength modifier*** if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing high jump, you can jump only half that distance.

With a Strength of 16, the monk has a +3 modifier and can usually make a high jump of 6 feet with a 10 foot running start.  With Step of the Wind, this is doubled to 12 feet.

Answer (score 4):

### 32 feet

Per the rules you cited, the long jump is doubled by *step of the wind*.

> You can spend 1 ki point to take the Disengage or Dash action as
>   a bonus action on your turn, ***and*** your jump distance is doubled for the
>   turn.

Long jump = 16 with the 10' run.  16 x 2 = 32.
Monk has 50' movement (100' if choosing Dash), but uses 10' for the run up: 40' (90') left.
Monk jumps 32 feet, with:

- 68' of movement left over to get to a target and strike them, or,
- 8' of moevment left over at the end of the jump to strike the target,
  and then Disengage.

*Source: [Basic Rules, p. 67](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=67); [SRD v. 5.1 page 2](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=27)7 (Step of the Wind)*