# What is the longest distance a player character can jump in one leap?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, movement

After asking [What is the longest distance a 13th-level monk can jump while attacking on the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/145245/42805), my curiosity got piqued.

**By RAW, what is the longest distance a player character can jump in one leap?**

The [jumping rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Jumping) state:

> **Long Jump.**
>
> When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet up to your Strength score if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.
>
> This rule assumes that the height of your jump doesn't matter, such as a jump across a stream or chasm. [...]

**Rules for answering this question:**

- Only classes from the books; multiclassing is allowed.
- You can make the character(s) level 20 (if required).
- The jumping character has allies that can aid in increasing the jump distance.
- For starting ability scores, use the standard array of 15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8.
- Spells are allowed, preferably without casting *Wish* (because of its unreliability).
- Shapeshifting is allowed.
- Magic Items are allowed, but only from the official books.
- There is no time limit for *preparing* the epic jump, although preferably within a day's worth of preparation.

**Related:** [What happens when you run out of movement while jumping?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57165/42805)

Comment: Is shapechanging allowed? (Wild Shape, Polymorph, Shapechange)

Comment: What is your stance on limited use items, like Manual of Gainful Exercise? In theory you can read it any number of times, wich would reduce this to how high can your movement speed be.

Comment: Since it is theoretical, you could get multiples of it (nobody said it is a unique item). Or be an elf and wait it out. Or *clone* yourself younger and wait a bit more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92549/discussion-between-vadruk-and-szega).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The furthest distance you can cover in one leap is **3,276 feet**

### The Jumper

- A Satyr (Found in [*Mythic Odysseys of Theros*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot)) Wizard (School of Transmutation) 17/Monk 2
  .
  (for Mirthful Leaps, spells, Trasmuter's Stone, Step of the Wind, and
  Unarmored Movement)

### The Ally

- A Wizard (Graviturgy Magic; found in *[Explorer's Guide to Wildemount](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/egtw)*)

### The Gear

- A pair of *[Boots of Striding and Springing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/boots-of-striding-and-springing)*
- A pair of *[Boots of Speed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/boots-of-speed)*
- A *[Belt of Storm Giant Strength](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/belt-of-storm-giant-strength)*
- A *[Potion of Speed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-speed)*

### The Setup

1. Our jumper begins by attuning to the three magic items he has collected over the years.
2. They cast *[glyph of warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding)* twice creating Spell Glyphs for the *[jump](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/jump)* and *[longstrider](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/longstrider)* spell.
3. They cast *[shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange)* assuming the form of a Female Steeder (found in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*) for the ***Extraordinary Leap*** trait.
4. They put on both pairs of boots and the belt.
5. They possess their transmuter's stone keyed to +10 of speed.
6. The ally uses Adjust Density on our jumper.
7. Our Jumper drinks the *Potion of Speed*.
8. They activate the Spell Glyph gaining the effects of *jump* and *longstrider*.
9. They use the Dash action three times (once with his/her regular action, once using Step of the Wind, and once using the action granted by the *haste* effect of the potion)
10. They perform a running long jump.

### The Jump

The maximum distance covered by the jump would be as follows:

- 29 feet from Strength score
- Doubled due to Adjust Density
- Tripled due to *Boots of Striding and Springing*
- +8 from Mirthful Leaps (since mirth is not a physical trait, it should carry over while *shapechange*d)
- All doubled due to Step of the Wind
- All tripled due to *jump*
- All tripled due to ***Extraordinary Leap***

<sup>the former two multipliers affect the "normal" distance, while the latter affect the total distance</sup>

Which totals to **3,276 feet** covered.

Then we just have to make sure our jumper has enough movement to make that jump:

> [From the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Jumping):] each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.

The burden is divided by three thanks to ***Extraordinary Leap***, resulting in a movement requirement of **1,092 feet**:

> every foot of its walking speed that it spends on the jump allows it to move 3 feet.

After factoring in the **10 feet** required for a running start, the jumper can satisify the total movement requirement of **1,102 feet** as demonstrated below:

- 30 feet of Walking Speed.
- +10 feet due to Unarmored Movement.
- +10 feet due to Adjust Density
- +10 feet due to *longstrider*
- +10 feet due to Trasmuter's Stone
- Doubled due to *haste*.
- Doubled due to *Boots of Speed*
- Quadrupled for movement due to three Dash actions.

Which totals to **1,120 feet** of movement.

---

*Relevant rules from the [Dungeon Master's Guide](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#WearingandWieldingItems):*

- On a steeder wearing boots:

> In most cases, a magic item that’s meant to be worn can fit a creature regardless of size or build. Many magic garments are made to be easily adjustable, or they magically adjust themselves to the wearer.

However it goes on to say:

> Rare exceptions exist. If the story suggests a good reason for an item to fit only creatures of a certain size or shape, you can rule that it doesn’t adjust.

Magic boots will usually work fine on flea-like legs, but if your GM decides that this is one such rare exception, you will have to create a Spell Glyph for *[alter self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alter-self)* to change your legs to have feet (thanks [@PierreCathé](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/45757/pierre-cath%C3%A9) in the comments for suggesting the glyph).

- On multiple boots:

> Use common sense to determine whether more than one of a given kind of magic item can be worn.

I propose that common sense allows an eight-legged creature to wear two pairs of footwear.

Comment: As both *shapechange* and *alter self* are concentration, you cannot have both active. (Both target Self, so allies cannot help either.)

Comment: @Szega good point. I'll take *alter self* out. No reason flea legs couldn't wear boots anyway

Comment: Whether a steeder can wear boots is at least a subjective matter. As DM I would rule no.

Comment: @Szega I'll make a note in the relevant rules section that it is tenuous

Comment: Alter Self can be cast using a Glyph of Warding

Comment: @PierreCathé good point, thanks. Added to the section about the ruling

Comment: I've proposed an edit that this will take three turns to complete. Is my reasoning valid here?

Comment: Ah, I see. I missed that part. Edit incoming for clarity

Comment: @Weasemunk accepted (although the numbers were a little off, I was already including the 10 feet)

Comment: Noticed that right after and provided a second edit, as I missed that you had already included it

Comment: @Szega Or whether it can wear two different sets of boots. I would say even if one ruled that it could wear magic boots and get the same effects, having 4 legs would require it to wear 4 boots, one for each leg, for it to work and thus could only wear and benefit from Boots of Striding and Springing OR Boots of Speed, but not both.

Comment: @Shufflepants The rules for paired items seems to disagree: "Items that come in pairs—such as boots, bracers, gauntlets, and gloves—impart their benefits only if both items of the pair are worn. For example, a character wearing a boot of striding and springing on one foot and a boot of elvenkind on the other foot gains no benefit from either item." Nothing indicates that they must occupy every eligible body part, in fact implying the opposite when it states "both" items (meaning two)

Comment: @DavidCoffron Pairs of boots are made for bipedal creatures. A boot for every leg. I agree that you have to be wearing both boots in the pair to get the effect. But that a creature with 4 legs ought to have to get their hands on a set of 4 magic boots to be able to get the full benefit, and thus are unable to wear 8 boots and get the effects of 2 different kinds of magic boots at the same time.

Comment: @Shufflepants that is definitely a house-rule (albeit a reasonable one), but I don't fault you for it. If that's how your table plays, enjoy it :)

Answer (score 7):

### 774 / 900 feet

You should be a tabaxi Monk 10 / Rogue(Thief) 3 / Fighter(Champion) 7. If magical Manual shenanigans are allowed, get your Strength and Dexterity scores to 30 with Manuals. If we care not for such, invest in a Belt of storm Giant Strength and use your 4 ASI-s to get a Dex of 20. You also pick up the Mobile feat. Then acquire a pair of Boots of Striding and Springing and get a wizard buddy who can cast *jump* and *haste*.
The wizard works his mojo on you, then you use Step of the Wind (Monk 2 feature).
Your movement is:

- 30 base + 20 unarmored movement (Monk) + 10 Mobile (feat) = 60 feet
- Feline Agility doubles that = 120 feet
- *haste* doubles again = 240 feet
- You can dash three times: with your action, your bonus action (Step of the Wind) and your *haste* action, letting you move 4 times your speed = 960 feet

Your long jump distance is:

- Strength score = 29 or 30 feet
- Remarkable Athlete (Champion 7) + Str mod = 38 or 40 feet
- Second-Story Work (Tief 3) + Dex mod = 43 or 50 feet
- Multipliers:

  - Boots of Striding and Springing triples
  - *jump* triples
  - Step of the Wind doubles
- Overall: *18, which get you to 774 or 900

Also leaving you with enough movement for a run up.

---

Thanks to Jack V. for pointing out the Belt and to Gandalfmeansme for adding Thief.

Comment: How about the Tabaxi trait: Feline Agility?

Comment: @Vadruk Increases movement speed, but does not affect jump distance. Thus it is of no use here.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then at the end of the jump, you're only left with 20ft of movement since you had to spend 10ft to do a long jump, right?

Comment: @PierreCathé Yes. I guess you could do a standing jump with the remaining speed, but I understood the question to mean *in one leap*.

Comment: Ability Scores [do have a maximum](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119438/41726)

Comment: Wasn't there some rule or ruling somewhere that indicated that if you have multiplicatives they don't multiply but add? x3 becomes x4 and not x9... I know it worked that way for critical damage in 3.X but thought there was something in 5E. Although it wouldn't surprise me that with the limited number of multiplicatives this was overlooked in the writing of the rules.

Comment: @Slagmoth depends on the feature. Difficult terrain, for example, is additive since it says "an additional foot of movement". nothing suggests others are additive instead of multiplicative in official rules or rulings.

Comment: @Slagmoth although there is some debate [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/83666/41726) (just found this).

Comment: @DavidCoffron The Manual also increases the maximum.

Comment: @Szega it increases the maximum for that character but does not increase the defined range that ability scores reside within. There is no 31st score for abilities.

Comment: Looking at other discussions on this, since magic items or spells are allowed, Storm Giant Strength gives you strength 29. A tabaxi's feline agility lets them move twice their speed. I think both of those should stack with the effects you already have.

Comment: Also, the athletics skill says "You try to jump an unusually long distance", which suggests you *can* exceed your jump distance. In 3.5e and 4e that was a skill check with DC equal to the distance, so I don't know if you could ever use that to jump further than the distance given with the jump spell or not.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Citation plz. I know of no such restriction. The PHB only notes that "monsters and divine beings can have scores as high as 30."

Comment: @Szega see the linked question for the citation. "the range of **possible ability scores, from 1 to 30**."

Comment: @Szega Great list. You might want to go Monk 10/Fighter(champion)7/Rogue(Thief)3. Thieves get to add their Dex modifier to their jump distance via Second Story Work. If you even have a +1 modifier, that would be another 6 feet. And you'd still have enough ASIs to max out strength and get a Feat.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can come up with is **954 feet**, with a movement for the round of at least 1040 feet (allowing 10 feet for a run up and some more left over). As a Tabaxi Monk/Barbarian/Rogue/Fighter with Haste, Potion of Storm Giant's Strength and several other spells going at once.

You can nearly treble that again if you decide a Steeder (a giant spider) can wear magic boots, for a total leap of **2754 feet**, or just over half a mile.

### Basic rules for jumping

In 5e, you can jump a distance equal to your strength score, provided you have a run-up of at least 10ft. But you can't jump further than your movement for the turn. It's a type of movement, not an action.

### Effects that increase jumping distance

I found most of these by searching DnDBeyond.com for "jump", or by reading other answers to similar questions on this site and on reddit.

- *Potion of Storm Giant Strength* sets your strength to 29.
- *Jump* spell triples your jump distance
- *Boots of Springing and Striding* also triple your jump distance
- *Step of the Wind* (Monk 3) doubles your jump distance (and allows you to take a bonus action to dash)
- *Remarkable Athlete* (Fighter 7) increases your jump distance by your strength modifier
- *Second Story Work* (Rogue 3) increases your jump distance by your dexterity modifier
- *Path of the Totem Warrior* with a Tiger spirit (Barbarian 3) increases your jump distance by 10ft
- *Wildshape* into a female steeder (Dex 16, CR 1, available as a *Circle of the Moon* Druid from level 2) which has an extraordinary leap ability that effectively triples jumping distance. In fact it's better than that as each foot of movement expended in jumping moves three feet, so if I'm reading it correctly, this isn't capped by speed, as long as the jump distance without the ability is less than the creature's speed for the turn.

### Effects that increase movement

- *Feline Agility* (Tabaxi race) doubles your speed for a turn
- *Haste* spell doubles your speed
- *Boots of Speed* doubles your speed
- Using three dash actions (with your action, your bonus action with rogue or monk ability, and the extra action from haste)
- A variety of abilities increase speed (Monk's *Unarmored Movement* by +10ft at 2nd level up to +30ft at 18th level) *Mobile* feat +10ft, *Longstrider* spell, etc)

### Jumping distance

Most of these effects stack. Lets assume a tabaxi Monk 2/Figher 7/Rogue 3/ Barbarian 3/Something 5, under the effect of a Potion of Storm Giant's Strength.

If "Something" brings monk up to level 6, and adds one level to rogue or barbarian, we get 15ft Unarmored Movement and four ability score increases. We could get more ASI or more Unarmored movement at the expense of the other one depending what classes we take.

With the benefit of four ability score increases on level up, she can use two of them to increase her dexterity to 20 (beginning at 15, +2 from Tabaxi), and one to take the mobile feat.

- Base jump 29 feet from 29 strength score
- +9 from *Remarkable Athlete*
- +5 from *Second Story Work*
- +10 from *Tiger Spirit* in *Path of the Totem Warrior*
- = 53 feet
- x3 from *Jump* spell, = 159 feet
- x3 from *Boots of Springing and Striding* = 477 feet
- x2 from *Step of the Wind* = 954

### Movement distance

- Base 30 feet
- +15 from Unarmored Movement
- +10 from *Mobile* feat
- +10 from *Longstrider* spell
- =65
- x2 due to *Feline Agility* = 130
- x2 due to *Haste* = 260
- x4 due to three Dash actions = 1040

### Alternate answers

I didn't use the Steeder's jump ability, as I think it can't wear magic boots, and if you have to choose either the Steeder's leap or the Boots of Springing and Striding, you have a slightly better result as a humanoid because you can have dex 20, instead of the default 16 for the Steeder.

For that version, replace three of the five unchosen levels with Druid 3 (Circle of the Moon). Reduce the bonus from Second Story Work from +5 to +3 because of the Steeder's dexterity. You don't need to worry about ASI as you're using the Steeder's physical stats.

Reduce the unarmoured Movement from the Monk to 10ft not 15ft.

I think that gives a jump of 918 feet, in a movement speed of 960 feet, so a little bit left over for the run up. The jump is then tripled due to steeder's ability, without taking up additional movement distance, for a total leap of 2754 feet.

### Caveats, quibbles and rules questions

I didn't ensure the character could cast all the spells themselves. If that's a requirement, you'd need the appropriate levels to cast Haste and some of the other spells.

I assumed *Jump* and *Boots of Springing and Striding* stack despite having similar effects.

There is never going to be a clear ruling on this. Officially, the same effects (the same magic, or game effects with the same name) don't stack, and everything else does stack. That's fine when there's a limited list of spells and abilities. But in a whole fantasy world, there must be variants, one country has "Jump" spell, and one has "Leap", which gives slightly more distance but has some other downside, and some other country has some other variant of the spell. Do those similar spells stack? It would be better if Jump were written to give a bonus to distance equal to your str score, or similar, so multiple jump spells COULD stack. But that's not the official rules at the moment. And it would still be capped by movement speed.

The athletics skill says it can be used to make leaps that are unusually far or high, but the specific examples cover only height not length. The 3.5e and 4e rules gave the DC for jumping as the distance of the jump, and 5e DCs should be a bit lower as ability scores are limited to a narrower range. But that would only make sense here if all of the extra bonuses were on top of that, because otherwise no character could make the skill DC to jump farther than their base distance, if it has all the bonuses described above.

Comment: Steeders are not beasts and thus you cannot Wild Shape into them. Also, as DM I would rule that Feline Agility and Remarkable Athlete come from body composition and are not retained in Wild Shape.